# DNS Server returning only name, no IP

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2016

I am having DNS server service running on Windows 2016 Server Primary Domain controller. I have an additional domain `smtw.in` configured:

[image]

[image: server config 2]
The PDC is the primary server for the domain.

I have a host `sfw3.smtw.in` configured with an A record as follows:

[image: host info in dns]

Now, when I run nslookup query from the PDC itself, I am getting the correct result as follows:
[image: server nslookup]

But when I run nslookup from a Win 11 Pro domain joined laptop, I am getting this empty result - only name is returned, no IP address:
[image: client error]

What could be wrong? I have tried restarting the PDC server, client etc. I have flushed cache, did 'Update Server data files' etc. but still the host is not resolving.

If I try to create some new hostname in the same zone, for example `sfw2.smtw.in` and try to resolve from the same client, it works, as below:
[image: another host]

Why? Please help.

Comment: Are you getting that same result when pointed at the other AD DNS servers in the domain? What about when testing from other domain clients? Does a ping or traceroute resolve the hostname to an IP?

Comment: @twconnell All other host names are resolving properly.  I tested from other domain clients, I am getting the correct response. Looks like an issue from this laptop only. Ping and tracert could not resolve host.

Comment: Update: Using wireshark, I find that nslookup is producing two queries: Standard A query for sfw3.smtw.in.sr___os.local and another AAAA query for the same hostname (sr___os.local is domain name of my AD network). OTOH a search for sfw2.smtw.in produces 4 queries: A and AAAA of sfw2.smtw.in.sr___os.local which fails, A and AAAA of sfw2.smtw.in. The query A for sfw2.smtw.in succeeds. Why does nslookup not search for sfw3.smtw.in alone and instead adds domain's "sr____os.local"?

Comment: if I add an entry in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file for sfw3.smtw.in, it resolves properly thereafter. but why?....

Comment: Does the laptop having the issue have any non-standard DNS suffixes configured?